# How do i clear Screen on AGENS command line

Tags: agens-graph

How do i clear screen on the AGENS Command Line ?

I tried using the following command

```
cl scr
clear screen
clear
cls
Ctrl + L
```

and most i could think of. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the code to clear the screen in agens is:

```
agens=# \! cls
```

Comment: I found this to be an OS-dependent feature. In Windows its \! cls but in Ubuntu it is \! clear

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get your question correctly, but I assume that you are trying to clear the console command.

If what I understand is correct, you may try the following command :

```
agens=# \! clear
```

It is just same as what we do in pg console.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this command to clear the AGENS command line

```
\! clear
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this command to clear the screen.

```
 \! clear
```

This is linux based ubuntu cli.

Following with agens=#